# How to force INPUT english character only on an html input field?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, character-encoding

I tried some solutions like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/DveuB/1021/

But it doesn't work when I am typing with **Vietnamese** keyboard

I can still input `á à ả à ư ...`, I have the same issue on Android with keyboard suggestion.

**Maxlength** attribute does not work when I use vietnamese keyboard also.

I have one example : https://www.theguardian.com/crosswords/quick/14718

But I don't know how they implemented?

I am using OSX

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a web application, you can use a regular expression for your input, with some mascara, well this is with an application created with Javascript or jQuery.